# How to Turn off HDD in Caddy using commands

Tags: sata

I have a HDD caddy installed in my laptop.
As i start my laptop, HDD caddy gets power-up and starts(Mounting remaining).

Can i manually turn it off? (Just to improve battery and heating) (without removing it).
Like disabling that sata port!!

Comment: You can in BIOS/UEFI. Otherwise the hardware will always be initialized. Whether or not it's also mounted in the OS is not that relevant as you may think. A mounted partition will require more energy from the system only if it's being accessed.

Comment: Once I have turn off HDD Caddy, I have to restart the machine again in order to turn HDD Caddy on, not exact thing i wanted... @CelticWarrior

Comment: I know and that's why I said it's not that relevant. While disabling it in BIOS/UEFI may very slightly improve battery life  (the power needed for a 2.5" HDD is really negligible, SSD even less), having it enabled and waiting to be mounted will not and that's the condition required for being able to mount. Screen brightness, CPU, GPU and others are what matters. One, two or three HDDs not much.